# How to prevente empty logging line in console

Tags: django, python-2.7, logging, console.log

Im new to django and I used django logging in my settings.py and also have one subprocess which contains another basicConfig. I dont know why do I have empty lines in my logger although once I added logfile and there was no empty line there. How can I get rid of these empty lines? The settings.py logging comes in the following:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    }
}
```

and this is logger example

```
 2021-08-24 11:30:58+0200 [-] 
 2021-08-24 11:30:58+0200 [-] Player.Protocol - DEBUG - 123 play
 2021-08-24 11:30:58+0200 [-] 
 2021-08-24 11:30:58+0200 [-] Player.Protocol - INFO - Starte subprocess fuer 
 2021-08-24 11:30:58+0200 [-] 
 2021-08-24 11:30:58+0200 [-] Player.Protocol - DEBUG - Closing Stdin
 2021-08-24 11:30:58+0200 [-]
```

the basicConfig for subprocess in python is :

```
logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
         ,stream=sys.stderr)
    logging.getLogger("Player").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by the second sentence of the question. Can you clarify what you mean by "once I added logfile and there was no empty line there"?  Are you saying that with the provided code, you sometimes see empty lines and sometimes not?  Or are you saying that you've used the logger in other circumstances and not had empty lines?

Comment: logfile (which is saved on HDD)does not have any empty lines. But console has empty lines (sometimes more sometimes less)